# For GitLab WebHook, how to make sure the request is from GitLab?

Tags: security, gitlab, webhooks

The GitLabdocument is here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/web_hooks/web_hooks.md

What I tried:

1. request.hostname: the host name can be faked?
2. request.ip: but I don't know gitlab's ips, and they may change in the future
3. I tried to find something like github's `Secret` when creating a webhook, the secret can be used to validate the body of request, but nothing
4. https: does it help?

So how to make sure the request is from GitLab? Is there a good way?

Comment: Can't you just look as source address?

Comment: @agilob you mean ip address?gitlab doesn't tell me their ip range in their document, as far as I know, and their ips may change in future, it do not looks like a good practice.

Comment: Depending on your implementation you should be able to see IP and domain which sent the request. Yes HTTPS does help, it's tied to a domain.

Comment: @agilob , thanks, but it's complicated, I will try the way as MrTux said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could include a secret token which you only enter in the gitlab frontend and is known to nobody else and then check that token on each request.

This could be added as a cgi parameter like `?token=somesecretvalue` at the end of the URL to the webhook when used with https.

Comment: Thanks, it is a doable way.

Comment: Still, the token can be discovered by accident (or intended) from the gitlab repository setting page, it can be used to fake requests to your webhook.
I guess the best method is to use the token + source ip address verification ...